# Filter Update Method does not cover with test class

Tags: apex, unit-test

I'm stuck and not sure where I'm going wrong. I have a user handler class that adds the user to a chatter group under different criteria. One when the user is created and one when the user is updated. It seems to work and my test class passes, however, I cannot get my filterupdate to be covered which makes the class coverage 67%..

In the handler it has the overrides for each dml statement:

```
<<snip>>
public override void beforeUpdate(Map<Id, SObject> oldMapGeneric, Map<Id, SObject> newMapGeneric){
    Map<Id, User> oldMap = (Map<Id, User>) oldMapGeneric;
    Map<Id, User> newMap = (Map<Id, User>) newMapGeneric;
    /*BEFORE UPDATE METHODS START*/

    // No coverage
    if(!isRecursive)
    {
        Set<Id> filtered = filterUpdate(newMap);
        addToGroups(filtered);
        isRecursive = TRUE;
    }
    /*BEFORE UPDATE METHODS END*/
}
<<snip>>

<<snip>>
public override void afterInsert(Map<Id, SObject> newMapGeneric){
    Map<Id, User> newMap = (Map<Id, User>) newMapGeneric;
    /*AFTER INSERT METHODS START*/
    if(!isRecursive)
    {
        // all lines covered
        Set<Id> filtered = filterInsert(newMap);
        addToGroups(filtered);
        isRecursive = true;
    }
    /*AFTER INSERT METHODS END*/
}
<<snip>>
```

I have a method for filtering on insert which has 100% coverage:

```
public static Set<Id> filterInsert(Map<Id, User> newMap)
{
    Set<Id> userIds = new Set<Id>();

    for(User u : newMap.values())
    {
        userIds.add(u.Id);
    }
    return userIds;
}
```

My method for update has 0% coverage:

```
public static Set<Id> filterUpdate(Map<Id, User> newMap)
{
    Set<Id> userIds = new Set<Id>();

    // Check if the user is active and we checked the Chatter group checkbox
    for(User u : newMap.values())
    {
        if(
            u.Add_To_Chatter_Group__c == TRUE &&
            u.IsActive == TRUE
        )
            {
                userIds.add(u.Id);
            }
    }
    return userIds;
}
```

This finally goes to an @future method to insert the user to the group:

```
@future
public static void AddToGroups(Set<Id> userIds)
{
    // The users that will be added to the group
    List<User> users = [SELECT id, Username FROM User WHERE id in :userIds];

    // Find the Chatter group Ids from the names of the custom setting "Chatter Auto Follow"
    List<CollaborationGroup> chatterGroups = [SELECT Id, Name 
                                              FROM CollaborationGroup 
                                              WHERE Name in :Chatter_Auto_Follow__c.getall().keySet()];

    // Create blank lists for inserting new records
    List<CollaborationGroupMember> chatterGroupMembers = new List<CollaborationGroupMember>();
    List<FeedItem> feedPosts = new List<FeedItem>();

    // loop the users that have been created
    for (User u : users)
    {
        // loop the groups
        for (CollaborationGroup chatterGroup : chatterGroups)
        {
            // add the user to the group
            CollaborationGroupMember cMember = new CollaborationGroupMember(
                CollaborationGroupId = chatterGroup.id,
                MemberId = u.Id);
            chatterGroupMembers.add(cMember);
        }
    }
insert chatterGroupMembers;

}
```

My test class has tests for the insert, update and the filter:

```
private class NPD_Test_UserTriggerHandler 
{
// Let's setup some test data to be used for all the tests.
@testSetup static void setupTestData()
{
    Chatter_Auto_Follow__c setting = new Chatter_Auto_Follow__c();
        setting.Name = 'Test Setting';
    insert setting;
}

// Functionality fires on insert so let's create the group then create a user and see if they are added as a member of the group
@isTest static void testInsert()
{
    // Create the group getting the group name from the custom setting
    Chatter_Auto_Follow__c[] settings = Chatter_Auto_Follow__c.getall().values();
    List<CollaborationGroup> groups = new List<CollaborationGroup>();
    for(Chatter_Auto_Follow__c cs : settings)
    {
        CollaborationGroup g = new CollaborationGroup(
            Name = cs.Name,
            CollaborationType = 'Public');
        groups.add(g);
    }
    insert groups;

    Profile p = [Select Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Standard User'];

    User u = new User();


    Test.startTest();
    insert u;
    Test.stopTest();

    // Verify that the user got added to the Group
    List<CollaborationGroupMember> cGM = [SELECT    Id, 
                                                    MemberId 
                                          FROM  CollaborationGroupMember 
                                          WHERE CollaborationGroupId = :groups AND
                                                MemberId = :u.Id];
    for(CollaborationGroupMember mem :cgM)
    {
        System.assertEquals(mem.MemberId, u.Id);
    }
}

// Functionality fires on edit so let's create the user, then create the group then update to add to the group
@istest static void testUpdate()
{
    // Create a user
    Profile p = [Select Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Standard User'];

    User u = new User();
    insert u;

    // Create the group getting the group name from the custom setting
    Chatter_Auto_Follow__c[] settings = Chatter_Auto_Follow__c.getall().values();
    List<CollaborationGroup> groups = new List<CollaborationGroup>();

    for(Chatter_Auto_Follow__c cs : settings)
    {
        CollaborationGroup g = new CollaborationGroup(
            Name = cs.Name,
            CollaborationType = 'Public');
        groups.add(g);
    }
    insert groups;

    // confirm User Checkbox is FALSE
    System.assertEquals(FALSE, u.Add_to_Chatter_Group__c);

    // Verify that there are no members added to group except the creator thus size is 1.
    List<CollaborationGroupMember> cGM = [  SELECT  Id, 
                                                    MemberId, 
                                                    CollaborationGroupId 
                                            FROM CollaborationGroupMember
                                            WHERE CollaborationGroupId IN :groups];
    System.assertEquals(1, cGM.size());

    // Update the user
    Test.startTest();
    u.Add_To_Chatter_group__c = TRUE;
    update u;
    Test.stopTest();

    // Verify that the user got added to the Group thus size is 2
    List<CollaborationGroupMember> cGMUpdate = [SELECT  Id, 
                                                        MemberId, 
                                                        CollaborationGroupId
                                                FROM CollaborationGroupMember 
                                                WHERE CollaborationGroupId IN :groups];
    System.assertEquals(2, cGMUpdate.size());
}

// Functionality runs when the record is updated. So we need to test the filter update method. 
@isTest static void testfilter()
{
    // Create a user
    Profile p = [Select Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Standard User'];

    User u = new User();
    insert u;

    System.assertEquals(FALSE, u.Add_To_Chatter_Group__c);

    u.Add_To_Chatter_Group__c = TRUE;
    update u;

    System.assertEquals(TRUE, u.Add_To_Chatter_Group__c);
}
```

}

is this the right way to test this out? Should I just make this a process builder action and stop stressing over code?

Comment: Your method for new should just return the keyset...nor do you actually ever test the filter. Call the method directly to test it, otherwise you are just testing the trigger, not the filter.

Comment: I don't get how you would call a method that checks if there is a value without updating, unless you do update?

    u.Add_To_Chatter_Group__c;
    SL_UserTriggerHandler.filterUpdate(u);
   update u;

Comment: You just pass in your inputs, and validate your outputs...it's like any other method and test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the filter testing, test the filter itself. For the rest, I think it's too broad and should at least be asked in a separate question.

```
static Integer dummyIdCount = 0;
static final String USER_PREFIX = SObjectType.User.getKeyPrefix();
static Id getDummyId()
{
    return USER_PREFIX + String.valueOf(dummyIdCount++).leftPad(15, '0');
}

static testmethod void testUpdateFilter_HappyPath()
{
    Map<Id, User> users = new Map<Id, User>();
    for (Integer i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        Id userId = getDummyId();
        users.put(userId, new User(Id=userId, IsActive=true, OtherCheckbox=true));
    }

    Test.startTest();
        Set<Id> results = filterMethod(users);
    Test.stopTest();

    system.assertEquals(users.keySet(), results,
        'Each record should be returned');
}
static testmethod void testUpdateFilter_NotActive()
{
    Map<Id, User> users = new Map<Id, User>();
    for (Integer i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        Id userId = getDummyId();
        users.put(userId, new User(Id=userId, IsActive=false, OtherCheckbox=true));
    }

    Test.startTest();
        Set<Id> results = filterMethod(users);
    Test.stopTest();

    system.assert(results.isEmpty(),
        'A record which is inactive should be ignored');
}
static testmethod void testUpdateFilter_NotChatter()
{
    Map<Id, User> users = new Map<Id, User>();
    for (Integer i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        Id userId = getDummyId();
        users.put(userId, new User(Id=userId, IsActive=true, OtherCheckbox=false));
    }

    Test.startTest();
        Set<Id> results = filterMethod(users);
    Test.stopTest();

    system.assert(results.isEmpty(),
        'A record which is not marked to add to a chatter group should be ignored');
}
```

Comment: I got this into my test class, happy path fails though, can you help with that here or is that a new question? I think it has to do with referencing the handler class method.

Comment: @DanWooding Just got time to circle back around on this. I didn't realize you were pulling the Id from the record, instead of using the map key. In your other question, javanoob correctly identified the key issue here. I updated my above tests to reflect that.